# Deprojecting a function with spherical simmetry integrated over axis

Tags: integration, inverse-function

Suppose we have a function $\phi(\vec r)$ and we have $\Psi(y,z)$ that is its integral over the $x$ axis, i.e.
$$\Psi(y,z) =\int_{-∞}^{+∞} \phi(x,y,z)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Of course there is no general way to recover $\phi$ starting from $\Psi$. Now let's explore the case where $\phi$ is spherically symmetric, so that we can write it as $\phi(r)$. Then, we can find $\Psi(R)$ in this way:
$$\Psi(R) =\int_{-∞}^{+∞} \phi(\sqrt{R^2+x^2})\,\mathrm dx,$$
where $R$ is the cylindrical radius. It easy to prove (change $s=\sqrt{R^2+x^2}$) that the above integral is equal to
$$\Psi(R) =2\int_R^{+∞} \phi(s) {\left(1+\left(R/s\right)^2\right)^{-1/2}}\,\mathrm ds.$$

**The question is**: How can I invert $\Psi(R)$ and recover $\phi(r)?$
Unluckily I cannot just make the derivative of $\Psi(R)$ because the variable $R$ appears in the right side both in the integration bounds and in the integrand.

Comment: Leibniz integral rule comes to mind. It doesn't require the boundary to be independent of $R$.

Comment: @TSU, I know, but  $d\Psi/dr$ will be the sum of the derivative over boundary and derivative inside integral, thus $\Psi$ still depends on a integral (of a derivative) of $\psi.$

Comment: hmm... your right, that didn't do the trick.